# Regular expression with conditional replacement

Tags: regex, awk, sed

I am trying to write a RegEx for replacing a character in a string, given that a condition is met. In particular, if the string ends in `y`, I would like to replace all instances of `a` to `o` and delete the final `y`. To illustrate what I am trying to do with examples:

```
Katy    --> Kot
cat     --> cat
Kakaty  --> KoKot
avidly  --> ovidl
```

I was using the RegEx `s/\(\w*\)a\(\w*\)y$/\1o\2/g` but it does not work. I was wondering how would one be able to capture the "conditional" nature of this task with a RegEx.

Your help is always most appreciated.

Comment: do you have to use sed? is this for a shell script?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to do it with `sed` or some shell equivalent

Comment: It should replace. I will add an example.

Answer (score 4):

With GNU sed:

If a line ends with y (`/y$/`), replace every `a` with `o` and replace trailing y with nothing (`s/y$//`).

```
sed '/y$/{y/a/o/;s/y$//}' file
```

Output:

```
Kot
cat
Kokot
ovidl
```

Comment: can also write `'/y$/{s///; y/a/o/}` to reuse the filter regex.

Comment: @glennjackman: Thanks for the hint. If I have seen this correctly, then I have to insert a semicolon with GNU sed: `/y$/{s///; y/a/o/;}`

Comment: huh, right. Oddly, you don't need the semicolon for `s/a/o/g`

Comment: the equivalent in perl offers no improvement: `perl -pe '/y$/ and do {s///;y/a/o/}'`

Comment: this doesn't seem to work when I try to replace `a` with say `to`. does it only work with substitutions of equal length?

Comment: @OrestXherija: yes. From `man sed`: *`y/source/dest/`: Transliterate the characters in the pattern space which appear in source to the corresponding character in dest.* Use `s/a/to/g`.

Answer (score 3):

You may use `awk`:

**Input:**

```
cat file
```

```
Katy
cat
KaKaty
avidly
```

**Command:**

```
awk '/y$/{gsub(/a/, "o"); sub(/.$/, "")} 1' file
```

```
Kot
cat
KoKot
ovidl
```

Answer (score 1):

You *could* use some sed spaghetti code, but please don't

```
sed '
    s/y$//     ; # try to replace trailing y
    ta         ; # if successful, goto a
    bb         ; # otherwise, goto b
    :a
    y/a/o/     ; # replace a with o
    :b
'
```